# Perl `map`: When to use EXPR vs. BLOCK form?

Tags: perl, dictionary

Perl newbie here.

The [Perl documentation for `map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) shows two usage forms:

- `map BLOCK LIST`
- `map EXPR, LIST`

I don't fully understand the semantic difference between the two.  When should I choose one form over the other?  Does the `EXPR` form limit me to one expression while the `BLOCK` form allows me to have multiple statements (more complex logic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference other than the syntax is the scope introduced by the curlies. For example,

```
>perl -E"use strict; map my $x = $_, 1,2,3,4; say $x"


>perl -E"use strict; map { my $x = $_ } 1,2,3,4; say $x"
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Both of those give me syntax errors:  `syntax error at -e line 1, near "my  ="`.  I'm running Perl v5.18.2.

Comment: Oops, shell is expanding `$x` -- need single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @Richard Hansen, It appears that you haven't correctly formatted the command for your shell.

Comment: So the `EXPR` form allows multiple statements like the `BLOCK` form?  If so, how would I do the following in the `EXPR` form:  `map({chomp; $_} @lines)`?

Comment: I thought it didn't need saying that one takes an expression and the other takes a block. Fixed.